# How do I separate my body from my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a page with three columns using a table but the table shows up on the navigation bar side.

[Here is what I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYxKc.png)

I want to separate the table from the top part so it looks like a regular website. I'm new to CSS so I don't know much about grids and boxes yet. Is there something I can do with my code?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
section {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(#98c9cd 3%, #e6c3c1 60%, #e4989e 100% );
}

header {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .logo
{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
   
}
header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a.active {
    background: white;
    color: #2b1055;
}

.container-flexbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% - 300px);
    width: calc(100% - 50px); /* RESIZE LATER IF NEEDED*/
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.container-flexbox .box {
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

.container-flexbox .box:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
}

.container-flexbox .box .imgBx
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .box .imgBx img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.table {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EAPP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles8.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://www.pngmart.com/files/10/Apple-Logo-PNG-Clipart.png" width="10%" height="18%" style="margin-top: 20px;"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="comfortcrate.html">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CPAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="bplanroot.html">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Biology</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    
        <section>
            <div class="table">
            <table border="1">
                <tr> 
                    <td colspan="3">EAPP</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/12B60/production/_109004667_02untitledgoosegamescreen3840x2160.png"></td>
                    <td><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/12B60/production/_109004667_02untitledgoosegamescreen3840x2160.png"></td>
                    <td><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/12B60/production/_109004667_02untitledgoosegamescreen3840x2160.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Heading 1<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et galisum fugit ad sapiente sapiente At architecto eligendi ab nostrum repellat et tenetur Quis et quisquam exercitationem non minus provident? Qui dolores corrupti id ipsam quia sit earum soluta. Aut internos velit et consequatur autem ut nesciunt assumenda. Ab saepe veniam et tempore adipisci aut fugit ducimus eos rerum atque aut quia modi ut enim neque.</td>
                    <td>Heading 2<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et galisum fugit ad sapiente sapiente At architecto eligendi ab nostrum repellat et tenetur Quis et quisquam exercitationem non minus provident? Qui dolores corrupti id ipsam quia sit earum soluta. Aut internos velit et consequatur autem ut nesciunt assumenda. Ab saepe veniam et tempore adipisci aut fugit ducimus eos rerum atque aut quia modi ut enim neque.</td>
                    <td>Heading 3<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et galisum fugit ad sapiente sapiente At architecto eligendi ab nostrum repellat et tenetur Quis et quisquam exercitationem non minus provident? Qui dolores corrupti id ipsam quia sit earum soluta. Aut internos velit et consequatur autem ut nesciunt assumenda. Ab saepe veniam et tempore adipisci aut fugit ducimus eos rerum atque aut quia modi ut enim neque.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "separate"

Comment: @Kameron The table should be just below the navigation bar. In the pictures, the navigation bar is on top of the table but I want the table to be below the nav bar.

Comment: Please update your snippet with a [example]. Currently, your snippet does not replicate the issue seen in the screenshot.

Comment: @Kameron I edited the snippet now

Comment: @smolbunny The updated snippet does not replicate the issue shown in the screenshot. Are you sure this is all the code? It's going to be hard for us to fix your problem if we cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is set `header { position: fixed;`

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}
section {
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(#98c9cd 3%, #e6c3c1 60%, #e4989e 100% );
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

header .logo
{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header ul {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
   
}
header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a.active {
    background: white;
    color: #2b1055;
}

.container-flexbox {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    height: calc(100% - 300px);
    width: calc(100% - 50px); /* RESIZE LATER IF NEEDED*/
    z-index: 100;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.container-flexbox .box {
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}

.container-flexbox .box:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
}

.container-flexbox .box .imgBx
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.container .box .imgBx img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: x-large;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.table {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EAPP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles8.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://www.pngmart.com/files/10/Apple-Logo-PNG-Clipart.png" width="10%" height="18%" style="margin-top: 20px;"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="comfortcrate.html">Overview</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CPAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="bplanroot.html">Entrepreneurship</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Biology</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    
        <section>
            <div class="table">
            <table border="1">
                <tr> 
                    <td colspan="3">EAPP</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/12B60/production/_109004667_02untitledgoosegamescreen3840x2160.png"></td>
                    <td><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/12B60/production/_109004667_02untitledgoosegamescreen3840x2160.png"></td>
                    <td><img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/976/cpsprodpb/12B60/production/_109004667_02untitledgoosegamescreen3840x2160.png"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Heading 1<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et galisum fugit ad sapiente sapiente At architecto eligendi ab nostrum repellat et tenetur Quis et quisquam exercitationem non minus provident? Qui dolores corrupti id ipsam quia sit earum soluta. Aut internos velit et consequatur autem ut nesciunt assumenda. Ab saepe veniam et tempore adipisci aut fugit ducimus eos rerum atque aut quia modi ut enim neque.</td>
                    <td>Heading 2<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et galisum fugit ad sapiente sapiente At architecto eligendi ab nostrum repellat et tenetur Quis et quisquam exercitationem non minus provident? Qui dolores corrupti id ipsam quia sit earum soluta. Aut internos velit et consequatur autem ut nesciunt assumenda. Ab saepe veniam et tempore adipisci aut fugit ducimus eos rerum atque aut quia modi ut enim neque.</td>
                    <td>Heading 3<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et galisum fugit ad sapiente sapiente At architecto eligendi ab nostrum repellat et tenetur Quis et quisquam exercitationem non minus provident? Qui dolores corrupti id ipsam quia sit earum soluta. Aut internos velit et consequatur autem ut nesciunt assumenda. Ab saepe veniam et tempore adipisci aut fugit ducimus eos rerum atque aut quia modi ut enim neque.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        </body>
        </html>
```